# Change WDR settings ONVIF C#

Tags: c#, camera, onvif

I want to change WDR settings of Avigilon camera through ONVIF using Ozeki SDK.

I have been looking into [this](http://www.camera-sdk.com/p_18-ip-video-camera-viewer-in-c-onvif.html) website but could not find any helpful information to change WDR settings.

Help please.

Answer (score 0):

WDR is the image sensor's  attribute. It's need image sensor driver support. It's a hardware support feature. You need use the matching SDK with the propped driver.

Comment: I used onvif protocol to achieve this task.

http://www.onvif.org/ver20/imaging/wsdl/imaging.wsdl